# File writing issue

Tags: java

This is my below code where I am trying to write the data in the file. but the values are not successfully written in the file also didn't thrown any exception as well. so I feel it could be an file permission issue. if that is the case then the exception would be thrown.

```java
public void setPrice(PriceDetails priceDetails)throws IOException { 
   priceoutputStream = new FileOutputStream(cacheFile);
   String priceDetailsString = priceDetails.toString();
   String valueString = priceDetailsString.substring(priceDetailsString.indexOf("=")+1);
   priceDetailsProperties.setProperty(formatPLU(priceDetails.getPlu()),valueString)??;
   priceDetailsProperties.store(priceoutputStream,null);
   priceoutputStream.close(); 
}
```

Could you help me out?

Comment: We can. But we won't - because we need the **exception trace** to be able to help...

Comment: Seems like there should be a `priceoutputStream.write()` in there somewhere.

Comment: And what does `priceDetailsProperties.store(priceoutputStream,null);` do?

Comment: I didn't get any exception but the values are not present in the file.

Comment: Where are you using priceoutputStream? You are not writing anything to the file how do you expect values to appear in it?

Comment: The priceDetailsProperties.store(priceoutputStream,null); will get the values from priceDetailsProperties and stored it to priceoutputStream.

Comment: The javadoc says "Properties from the defaults table of this Properties table (if any) are not written out by this method.". Also you could try a non-null second parameter.

Comment: @Kevin DiTraglia, @Aniket Thakur: the `priceDetailsProperties.store()` writes to the file - or better said should write. I'm confused by the question: You say right before the code-block, that this code DID throw an exception. Did it or not?

Comment: there is not need write when we use store.

Comment: no @ kevin: I said the code ddin't thows any exception. plz see above.

Comment: The same code is working fine in windows environment. the issue started when i moved to Linux platform.

Comment: @user1280096 you wrote `The method which contains below code throws IOException.` in the question. Does this mean the code does not throw exception? To me it does not seem not to throw an exception. But English is _neither_ my native language...

Comment: Oh sorry what i mean say like i have written the code of "throws IOException" in the method definition.

Comment: What is _the excpetion_? The full stacktrace...

Comment: There is no exception occurred and the data also not written in the file...
See below full code for reference:

Comment: public void setPrice(PriceDetails priceDetails)throws IOException
    {
priceoutputStream = new FileOutputStream(cacheFile);
        String priceDetailsString = priceDetails.toString();
        String valueString = priceDetailsString.substring(priceDetailsString.indexOf("=")+1);
        priceDetailsProperties.setProperty(formatPLU(priceDetails.getPlu()),valueString);
        priceDetailsProperties.store(priceoutputStream,null);
        priceoutputStream.close();
}

Comment: so what could be the reason?

Comment: please find the edited question.

Comment: What is the value of cacheFile?  File paths and working directories are different in Unix.  Sure you are looking in the right place?

Comment: This is an exercise in futility until you tell us the value of `cacheFile`.  Why do I have a feeling it contains silly _backslash_ characters that are only used by Windows...

Answer (score 0):

- I think we can simply do this using another way, as there is **no binary data** to write or read we can use `Reader and Writer with Buffers.`

**Please try the following code to write it to the file:**

```
File f = new File("Path");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

bw.write("Your Data"); 

bw.close();
```